# is it possible to get rid of infinity?

Tags: java, eclipse, events, infinity

I'm making a scientific calculator in Java, and I tried to put the division in a try/catch statement in case it tries to divide by zero. When I tested it, the outcome was "Infinity". I don't want that.

Comment: This is the normal behavior. So what do you want instead?

Comment: Check the result after the calculation, and then throw if it's infinity, if you want to use exceptions.

Comment: @Radiodef I want it to say "DON'T DIVIDE BY ZERO".